# Is there any pitfalls for using different ports for different feature in Web Application?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client-server

I am building a webApp with Mean Stack. My webApp includes a chat feature. I used socket.io for chat implementation. Now I have implemented socket.io in one port and the express server on usual port 80.

Now I have another feature (Screensharing) for which I would also like to use socketio but on a different port. I am using different ports because it is making the code a lot simpler and easier to understand.

But as I am new to web development , I was wondering if there are any pitfalls for using multiple ports in the long run ?

Because in my limited experience I don't see people using different ports too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pitfall i found when use multiple ports: some user's network environment disallow access non-standard ports(only 80 for http and 443 for https is allowed), this means you can't deploy many services on one machine.

Comment: How common is that type of environment?  Our target user is normally home user , not in office environment ...

Comment: For home user, may be there is no problem, but standard ports(80 and 433) always the most firewall friendly, and we can't assume all user's network environment is normal. If your service(such as web sites)'s url will expose to users(browser address bar, share on bbs), with strange ports on url will looks like not professional, for internal api service, this is not a problem. May be you can deploy nginx as frontend for all your services, with virtual hosts, you get the standard ports and standalone services.

Comment: Thanks , It is actually for internal api service not visible in browser. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: This is a good point. I've seen cases where firewalls will block ports and your UI will be unable to take part in cross origin communication. Just to add to this point, socket.io DOES allow cross origin. As outlined here however, you may run into issues. It depends on who your target user is (home user is probably fine).